# C Compiling on iOS

Tags: ios, c, compilation

Ok this might appear as a bit of a silly question.

I used the below link to install gnu compiler on my iPad 4th generation.
http://iklive.org/cc-compiling-on-ios/

I didn't experience any sort of a glitch in the installation.

What i would like to know now is how will i be able to compile and executed these programs. Btw i use Textastic for text editing.

Like i said before this might appear as a silly question. So please don't judge me.

Thank you for you time.

Comment: `Objective-C` can compile `C` programs. If you are developing a `C` application using your Mac, use Xcode to build it.

Comment: The link provided in your question describes exactly how to install the software required and then the steps to follow to compile C programs on your iPad. What problem are you having exactly?

Comment: I got error 404